# One review per user in the current title

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make so that every user could only post one review per title (product). First idea was to do this through UniqueTogether, but it resulted unsuccessful. So now, I thought to complete it by validate in serializer.

Right now I am getting the following error:
`TypeError: Review() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'`. But if you look at my code below I did not pass `title` argument to Review(). I even tried to make error on purpose to see what arguments I can pass to Review() and `title` was not there.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'title_d' into field. Choices are: author, 
author_id, comments, id, pub_date, score, text, title_id, title_id_id
```

serializers.py

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(),
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'author', 'score', 'pub_date')

    def validate(self, data):
        title_id = self.context['view'].kwargs['title_id']
        author = self.context['request'].user
        if Review.objects.filter(title_id=title_id, author=author).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'You cannot post second review on same item.'
            )
        return data
```

models.py

```
class Review(models.Model):
    title_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Title,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='reviews'
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        'Текст отзыва'
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        verbose_name='Автор',
        related_name='reviews'
    )
    score = models.IntegerField(
        choices=SCORES
    )
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Дата публикации',
        auto_now_add=True,)



class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Название произведения'
    )

    year = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Год произведения'
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        verbose_name='Категория произведения',
        related_name='category_title',
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Описания произведения',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    rating = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Рейтинг произведения',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    genres = models.ManyToManyField(
        Genre,
        through='GenreTitle',
    )
```

views.py

```
class ReviewViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    permission_classes = [ReviewAndComment, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        title = get_object_or_404(Title, id=self.kwargs['title_id'])
        return title.reviews.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        title = get_object_or_404(Title,
                                  id=self.kwargs['title_id'])
        author = get_object_or_404(User,
                                   username=self.request.user)
        reviews = Review.objects.filter(title=title.pk)
        scores = reviews.values_list('score', flat=True)
        scores = list(scores)
        scores.append(serializer.validated_data['score'])
        rating = sum(scores) / len(scores)
        title.rating = round(rating)
        title.save()
        serializer.save(title=title,
                        author=author)
```

Comment: please make sure you match title object instead obj title.pk ```reviews = Review.objects.filter(title=title.pk)``` change to ```reviews = Review.objects.filter(title=title)```

Answer (score 1):

Change name of `title_id` field into 'title'. Also in validation do one change:

```
def validate(self, data):
    title = int(data['title'])
    author = self.context['request'].user   # here maybe self.request.user might work too
    if Review.objects.filter(title=title, author=author).exists():
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried method you just mentioned successfully renamed title_id to title, but now getting this error `KeyError: 'title'`. Little confused why we it is happening, in my model of Review it is clear that we have title field. Added my views.py file of Review, maybe problem is there and I can not see it.

Comment: `KeyError: 'title' `on making a post request?

Comment: @Qaimaq Please share your template, because it might be a problem there.